# How to use WHERE query at same column in same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have this data.

```
tbl_data

id    value
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       A
2       C
```

I want to select id which have 'A' and 'B' as value.

```
SELECT id FROM tbl_data WHERE value = 'A' AND value = 'B'
```

But it returns zero result.

How to make it to return id 1 ?

Comment: Is there any **single row** that contains both `A` and `B` in the same column?

Comment: @NicoHaase no, the value always one character A or B or C.

Comment: What's the problem with using `OR` then?

Comment: @SamChats it will return id 1 and 2.

Comment: @Yusufmm, got it, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select id from table 
where
value  in ('A', 'B')
group by id 
having count( distinct value ) = 2
```

Comment: Can you explain this part? ```having count( distinct value ) = 2``` Does it mean that if i want to select A, B, and C than it will become ```= 3```?

Comment: `Does it mean that if i want to select A, B, and C than it will become = 3`, Yes, that's correct

Comment: @Yusufmm - just you need also `C` in `where` clause too,   `where
value  in ('A', 'B', 'C')`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the solution of @OTAR is to use a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t ( ID INT, value TEXT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
(1,'A'),(1,'B'),(1,'C'),(2,'A'),(2,'C'),(2,'F');


WITH j AS (
  SELECT id,array_agg(value) AS arr
FROM t GROUP BY id)
SELECT * FROM j
WHERE arr @> ARRAY['A','B'];

 id |   arr   
----+---------
  1 | {A,B,C}
(1 Zeile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply execute the following:

```
SELECT min(id) FROM table WHERE value in ('A','B');
```

Comment: you can use min(id).